# Wordpress - Restrict page by user role - URL Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, function, if-statement, redirect

I am trying to restrict a page for all user roles except "librarian"

I've got a library dashboard on `example.com/library-dashboard`

When a loogged in user role that is not 'librarian' visits this page, I need to redirect them to `example.com/subscription-needed`

I am using the following function for this:

```
function is_corr_user($page_slug) {

  // User has to be logged in
  if(!is_user_logged_in())
    return false;

  // All user roles
  $roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

  // For each page check if user has required role
  switch($page_slug) {
    case "library-dashboard":
     return in_array('librarian, administrator', $roles);
    default:
      return false;
  }
}


// Hook to wordpress before load and check if correct user is on page
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse69369_is_correct_user' );
function wpse69369_is_correct_user()
{
    global $post;

    // Redirect to a custom page if wrong user
    if(!is_corr_user($post->post_name)) {
      wp_redirect( '/subscription-needed/' );
      exit;
    }     
}
```

My issue is that this function now redirects all pages to `example.com/subscription-needed/` including the homepage and I am getting too many redirects error.

How can I fix this, so the function only works for the given user role `librarian` on the page `example.com/library-dashboard` ?

So what I'm trying to achieve is that if `librarian` & `administrator` visits `example.com/library-dashboard` then nothing happens and the page shows as normal.

But If any other user role that is NOT `librarian` & `administrator` visits the page `example.com/library-dashboard`, they should be redirected to `example.com/subscription-needed/`

Comment: I think in line #28/#26, you should use `is_corr_user()` and not `is_correct_user()`..

Comment: You're absolutelly right! The fatal error is gone, but another issue just came up.

Comment: For some reason my homepage is now redirecting to the `/subscription-needed/` page. Why is that?

Comment: Yes this is how it works why because you haven't specified any particular page and hence it works for all page including homepage

Comment: @JoeBloggs please edit your question as you found the solution for this question (Fatal error problem) but seems that you ask different problem

Comment: @VigneshPichamani the question is now edited to reflect the new issue .. would you be please able to post your solution in an answer? Thanks

Comment: @VigneshPichamani btw. didn't I specify the page in the above string `case "library-dashboard": ` ?

Comment: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/j3FMhZiy), which you can use in place of both the `is_corr_user()` and `wpse69369_is_correct_user()` functions.

Comment: Hey @SallyCJ, your code works great! Many thanks for that. If you can post it as an answer, I'll be really happy to upvote and mark as correct.

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, which you can use in place of both the `is_corr_user()` and `wpse69369_is_correct_user()` functions:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'librarian_dashboard_redirect' );
function librarian_dashboard_redirect() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'library-dashboard' ) ) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $valid_roles = [ 'administrator', 'librarian' ];

        $the_roles = array_intersect( $valid_roles, $user->roles );

        // The current user does not have any of the 'valid' roles.
        if ( empty( $the_roles ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/subscription-needed/' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `if(array_intersect($valid_roles, $user->roles))`?

Comment: Yes, sure, @markmoxx. But back then, if I recall it properly, I had `var_dump( $the_roles );` in the original code. And when I wrote the answer, I removed just the `var_dump()` and kept the rest as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Check with below code.

```
add_action('wp', 'redirectUserOnrole');
function redirectUserOnrole() {
 //First i am checking user logged in or not
 if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = (array) $user->roles;
    //checking for the user role you need to change the role only if you wish
    if ($role[0] != 'librarian' || $role[0] != 'administrator') {
        global $post;
        if ($post->post_name == 'library-dashboard') {
            wp_redirect('/subscription-needed/');
            exit;
        }
    }
 } else {
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey Akshay, I think you've got it the other way around .. I am getting redirected as a librarian now. .. It should be like this: _IF the user role `IS NOT librarian` or `IS NOT administrator`, then redirect to `/subscription-needed/` , but `IF the user IS librarian` or `IS administrator`, then stay on the current `library-dashboard` page_

Comment: Ok you can change my if condition and i am sure you will get you results. Code is correctly working without any error.

Comment: Okay how do I correctly change the If condition? .. would it be: `if (!$role[0] == 'librarian') {` ? Adding just the `!` exclamation into the string? Would you be please able to edit your answer? Thanks

Comment: Hey Akshay, many thanks for changing the code. I'm trying to test it, but it actually doesn't work. I'm still getting redirected as librarian as well as administrator ..

Comment: Check the with $role do the print_r and check the array does it have exact string with which we have set in condition